# Is it possible to be a Canvas App and also an iPhone app?

Tags: ios, facebook

According to the Facebook documentation, you need to be a Canvas app in order to perform Requests and access other nifty features.  But Facebook requires that you use Facebook Credits to be a Canvas App.  This seems to be in conflict with Apple's App Store, since in-app purchases would use Apple's payment methods and not Facebook Credits.

Does anyone know how to resolve payments in this situation between Apple and Facebook?
Do either company allow developers to use the other's payment method?
Do things change if you are an HTML5 hybrid app rather than a native app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user visits your app via canvas (whether on the web or on the "mobile web" in a mobile web browser) all payments should be handled using Facebook Credits. When the user is accessing your app through its native iOS application, payments should be handled using Apple's payments system.

Answer (score 1):

According to Facebook you have to use iTunes payments instead of Facebook Credits in a native iOS app.
Look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/